# Parse.comでクエリを最新50件のみ取得したいのですが

Tags: ios, swift, parse.com

Parse.comで最新クエリ50件だけ取得したいのですが、どうすればよろしいでしょうか？
言語はSwiftです。
以下のコードはすべてのクエリを取得しています。最新50件のみを取得するためにはどうすれば良いでしょうか。

```
func loadData() {

comments.removeAllObjects()
var query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Comment")
query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
query.limit = 1000
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{(objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if (error != nil){
        //error
    }


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
        // Task
        for object in objects {

            if object["commentId"] as? String == nil {
            self.comments.addObject(object)
                if  self.comments.count == 50 {
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            // UI
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.stopIndicator()
        }
    }
}
```

}

回答よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

query.limit = 50
でどうでしょう。